# Wrong icon on task bar

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-xe2, taskbar

Delphi XE2 app in WIndows 10, running under Parallels V11. This project was started by copying another, deleting .dsk and .local and changing form and pas file names. The dpr and .dproj were edited.

I changed the icon on the form and in Project|Options. It makes no difference if "Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;" is present or not. The icon that shows up on the task bar is the one from the original project. It makes no difference if the program is run in the IDE or independently. I have shut down and restarted XE and Win 10.

If I run the program on another machine(Win 7) the correct icon is shown on the task bar.

Comment: Do some debugging. Use a resource editor to inspect the resources linked to the executable file. Look at the icon named MAINICON.

Comment: i wonder in win10 changed requirements for color depth or resolution for desktop/taskbar icons. At least once Windows did it between 2000 and Vista. His icon might contain DIFFERENT pictures for different situations.

Comment: @David I've looked in every file I could in the project, with no results. I can't find MAINICON.

Comment: @Arioch The icon is a single .ico image.

Comment: Let me try again. Maybe some bold will help. Use a **resource editor** to inspect the resources linked to the executable file. Look at the icon named MAINICON.

Comment: few examples of such editors, opening .EXE and looking inside:  NtCore CFF Explorer Suite, Total Commander or Unreal Commander with http://totalcmd.net/plugring/peviewer.html

Comment: @David OK on the bold ;-). I could not get 7zip to unpack the RE I tried. I'll try another one. It's a moot point now, the problem went away after I restarted the 'puter for an unrelated reason.

Comment: @Arioch - Thanks for the list. I'll try them. PEViewer wouldn't unpack.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem went away after I restarted the computer.

Well, yes. Windows caches icons. They get refreshed after a restart.

Comment: The cache wasn't cleared after the first 2 reboots. If it was a cache issue, which seems likely but unproven.

Answer (score 0):

Because the window that is rendered as a button on the taskbar and the mainwindow are two different windows.

One is `Application.Handle` while another is `Application.MainForm.Handle`

You have two options.

1. Change the icon in IDE's Project Options of your EXE
   [image]
2. Do it using Windows GDI API

.

```
 var hIcon: THandle;

 hIcon := LoadIcon(MainInstance, PChar('Whatever_Taskbar_Icon_Resource_Name'));
 if hIcon > 0 then
       Application.Icon.Handle := hIcon;
```

3. One more exotic options is that your ico-file contains drastically different images for different Resolution/ColorDepth combinations. It is sometimes forgotten that icon files are not images but are arrays of images. Good images viewer like IrfanView, XnView, Imagine, etc should be able to display all the images of the array the .ico file contains.

Comment: Not so when `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar = True`.

Comment: @Arioch 1. As I said in the OP, that is already set correctly. 2. No effect. 3. There is no multi-image icon file, only a single image .ico. It's like Win has cached the wrong icon somewhere.

Comment: @David What are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the first sentence in the answer which is factually incorrect when the main form is the taskbar window